# Problems with Chaining in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, chaining

I have the following problem, I'm trying to make a small chained.

```
(function(window){
window.de=de={}

de.one=function(s){if(s){var y=document.getElementById(s); return y;} return this;}

de.two=function(s2){alert(s2); return this;}

})(window)
```

this is what I try to:

```
de.one("Id").two("Hello!");
```

but the console gives me this error:

*TypeError: Object # has no method 'two'*

Comment: You are returning y(which is the html element) not `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you an idea:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mvEfP/2/)**

```
(function(window){

var myLibrary = (function( s ) {
  var d = document,
      e = d.getElementById( s ),
      methods = {
        one : function(val){
            alert(val);
            return this; // maintain chainability
        }, 
        two : function(val){
            alert(val);
            return this; // maintain chainability
        },
        css : function( property, val){
            if(!val && typeof property == "object" ){ // styles in Object notation
                for(var key in property){
                    e.style[key] = property[key];
                }
            }else{ // Comma separated: property, value
                e.style[property] = val || undefined;
            }
            return this;    
        }
    };
    return methods;

});
window.myLibrary = window.de = myLibrary; // Make Window accept "de" as "myLib" alias.   

})(window);
```

```
de("Id").one("UGA!!!").two("yoo").css({color:"red", background:"gold"});
```

taking in consideration that you have something like:

```
 <div id="Id">Some element</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The console isn't lying. `HTMLElement` doesn't have a method named `two`, as that method belongs to `window.de`.

Don't modify host objects like `HTMLElement` by adding to their prototype. They aren't implemented in JavaScript.

Write a wrapper that contains your methods instead, sort of like jQuery:

```
(function(window) {
    var de = function(thing) {
        return new de.prototype.init(thing);
    };

    de.prototype = {
        constructor: de,

        init: function(thing) {
            this.thing = thing;
        },

        one: function(other) {
            return de(other);
        }
    };

    de.prototype.init.prototype = de.prototype;

    window.de = de;
})(window);
```

Now, you can do:

```
de('foo').one('bar').one('bar').one('baz')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, the problem is in de.one(), you have 2 different TYPES of return values.

"return y" and return "this".  If you want to chain, you have to "this".